# How would I loop something until a specific requirement is met

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a number guessing game that loops until you get the number correct. So far I have only been able to use "for i in range(10)" but if the user gets the number correct in less than 10 tries, the program keeps looping 10 times. How could I fix this.

So far, this is what I have tried,

```
for i in range(10):
            guess1 = int(input ('Guess the number: '))
            if guess1 > rn1:
                print('Lower.')
            elif guess1 < rn1:
                print('Higher.')
            else:
                guess1 == rn1
                print('Correct!')
```

Comment: You use `break` to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track with your number guessing game! To ensure that the loop stops as soon as the correct number is guessed, you can use a while loop instead of a for loop. Here's how you could modify your code:

```
# Generate the random number 'rn1' and initialize the 'attempts' variable
rn1 = ...  # Replace with your random number generation logic
attempts = 0

# Start the guessing loop
while True:
    guess1 = int(input('Guess the number: '))
    attempts += 1

    if guess1 > rn1:
        print('Lower.')
    elif guess1 < rn1:
        print('Higher.')
    else:
        print('Correct!')
        break  # Exit the loop when the correct number is guessed

# Print the number of attempts it took
print(f'Congratulations! You guessed the number in {attempts} attempts.')
```

This way, the loop will continue running until the correct number is guessed, regardless of the number of attempts. Once the correct number is guessed, the loop will be exited using the break statement.

Feel free to adapt this example to fit your specific code structure and requirements. If you have any further questions or need additional assistance, please don't hesitate to ask.